# Hide text without keeping space

Tags: phantom

I want to hide some text but :

- I **don't want** the hidden text to take space
- I still want that LaTeX parse the content (to keep numbering)

I have found this solution :

```
\vphantom{\hphantom{text}}
```

This work perfectly but is there any better way to do it (I feel like latex probably already have a command for that and I just need to find it's name) ?

Comment: If you say you want to keep numbering, maybe more information on what you are actually trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: I have my main document containing a lots of things. This will generate my main pdf. But I will also want to generate some pdf with only some part of my document or without some part of my document but I need everythings else to stay the same so I need to have all counter to be the same that the main document.

Comment: @Matheod best way is probably to put each section in a separate file and use `\includeonly` to specify which sections you want to use. All numbering is then preserved.

Comment: `\includeonly` might work in some case but not all because it require a new page.

Answer (score 2):

The phantom construct makes a zero-sized box, but it can affect the spacing of surrounding constructs, see the middle column, below. You can simply set the text in a box, then not use the box.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{p{2cm}|}}
\hline
a

b
&
a

\vphantom{\hphantom{text}}

b
&
a

\sbox0{text}

b
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Section seems to make sbox broke. Example :

`
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{a}


\sbox0{b

c

\section{d}


e}

\section{f}


\end{document}
`

Comment: @Matheod yes same would be true of `\hphantom` as you said that worked perfectly I assumed that you only needed horizontal mode material. You can use `\sbox0{\vbox{...\section...}}`  but there are still other things that would fail eg `\begin{figure}`

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I've been using for years.  It may not be exactly what you want, but it works for my.

\newcommand{\noop}[1]{}

It takes one argument and does absolutely nothing with it.

I use it for "commenting out" text or equations that I might want to use, and might not.  It's useful for developing docs.  When my doc is ready, I just delete all the \noop blocks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).